# multi-label text classification from single label dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset with a single label per document like the example below.

```
  label           text

  pay            "i will pay now"
  finance        "are you the finance guy?"
  law            "lawyers and law"
  court          "was at the court today"
  finance report "bank reported annual share.."
```

The text document can be labelled with more than one label, so how can I do a multi-label classification on this dataset? I've read a lot of documentation from `sklearn`, but I can't seem to find the right way to do multi-label classification on a single-label dataset. Thanks in advance for any help.

So far, this is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn import preprocessing

loc = r'C:\Users\..\Downloads\excel.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(loc)
X = np.array(df.docs)
z = np.array(df.title)
y = np.array(df.raw)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, 
random_state=42)

mlb = preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()
Y = mlb.fit_transform(y_train)
Y_test = mlb.fit_transform(y_test)

classifier = Pipeline([
('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))])

  classifier.fit(X_train, Y)
  predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)

 doc_new = np.array(['X has announced that it will sell $587 million'])

 print("Accuracy Score: ", accuracy_score(Y_test, predicted))
 print(mlb.inverse_transform(classifier.predict(doc_new)))
```

But I keep getting a dimensional error:

> .format(len(self.classes_), yt.shape[1]))ValueError: Expected indicator for 44 classes, but got 46

Answer (score 0):

I fould the solution. I used pandas GroupBy

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(["id", "doc"]).label.apply(list)).reset_index()
```

to group text with more than one class together and it worked.

the dimension error has also been solved: [dimension error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671194/inconsistent-shape-error-multilabelbinarizer-on-y-test-sklearn-multi-label-clas)